# Create writeable multi table select query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with below schema

Table 1 -

```
id, Serial Code,  Hours   
xxxx-aa, 1
xxxx-bb, 2
yyyy-aa, 1
```

Table 2 -

```
Stage , Description 
aa, foo
bb, bar
```

Right now my joins are like this.

```
SELECT x.*, y.Description
FROM table1 x LEFT JOIN
     table2 y
     ON MID(serial, 6, 2) = y.stage
```

this gave me the desire result. however, it is readable only. I know I can create a writeable query if i separate out the foreign key in table 1 so the joining condition is

```
SELECT x.*, y.Description
FROM table1 x LEFT JOIN
     table2 y
     ON x.stage = y.stage
```

but is there a better way to create a writeable query without .. un-normalize.. table 1?

thanks.

Comment: I think you need to have the primary key of the second table in your SELECT statement. But even then, a LEFT JOIN may not be writeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a calculated column called [stage] in table 1 and define it  MID(serial,6,2).   As you fill up the table, this column is automatically populated and allows you to query it simply as if you "un-normalized" table 1.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about calculated fields. I did as you say and now the query is writeable, this is the link about calculated fields [link](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html) in case others are reading.